# Can you define more stages within one GitLab template?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

i'm creating a GitLab Template that i can import in my pipeline through `include` and `extends`.

The question is:
can i define more then one stage to be imported within a single template? Something like (as an example but the structure is the same):

```
.template: 
  image:
      name: someimage

  variables:
      GITLAB_URL: "${CI_SERVER_URL}"

  test1:
    stage: test
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
    script:
      - echo test
            
  test2:
    stage: .post
    rules:
    variables:
        CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER: "GitLabDashboard"
        CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER_IMPL: ${CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER}
    script:
      - echo "some other test"
    artifacts: 
      reports:
        results: results.json
```

For now this setup is not working for me. Even tho in the editor i'm able to see the imported yml, the stages are not executed.
Any clues?
Thanks :)

**UPDATE**

After some tests, i got a different template. The problem is that the stage is not executed. So in this case, the stage test, is not there.
If i open the editor with the merged yml, i see this:

```
---
".template":
  image: someimage
  variables:
    GITLAB_URL: "${CI_SERVER_URL}"
  rules:
  - if: $SECURITY_DASHBOARD_ON_MR == "true" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    variables:
      CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER: GitLabDashboard
      CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER_IMPL: "${CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER}"
  script:
  - echo "test"
default:
  image: somedefaultimage
  tags:
  - sometag
stages:
- ".pre"
- build
- test
- deploy
- ".post"
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "Running build..."
test:
  image: someimage
  variables:
    GITLAB_URL: "${CI_SERVER_URL}"
  rules:
  - if: $SECURITY_DASHBOARD_ON_MR == "true" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    variables:
      CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER: GitLabDashboard
      CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER_IMPL: "${CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER}"
  script:
  - echo "test"
  stage: test
  extends: ".scan"
deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  script:
  - echo "Deploying application..."
  - echo "Application successfully deployed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in your example is incorrect - it is not possible to define job inside another job or [job template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html#template-types).

Corrected template:

```
.template: 
  image:
    name: someimage
  variables:
    GITLAB_URL: "${CI_SERVER_URL}"

test1:
  extends: .template
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
  script:
    - echo test
        
test2:
  extends: .template
  stage: .post
  variables:
    CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER: "GitLabDashboard"
    CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER_IMPL: ${CX_FLOW_BUG_TRACKER}
  script:
    - echo "some other test"
  artifacts: 
    reports:
      results: results.json
```

After including this template into your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file - do not forget to add `test` stage to stages section. [.post](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stage-post) stage is included by default.

Comment: Thank you very much. Still, also with this solution and your suggestions, the stage won't get executed. Is very difficult to debug, any suggestions? The fact that it the stage is not showed, means that there is an error in the yml? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `rule` from `test` stage is true? one of the `rules` has to be true in another case job will not be included into pipeline